# How to set a fixed size for img tag?

Tags: html, css, image, containers, max-size

I want the img to have a fixed size let's say for example 290x193 and don't get changed with the image's actual width and height, I tried inline CSS on img tag but it does not work. is there any bootstrap class for this purpose rather than defining CSS?

here is my code:

```
           <?php foreach($articles as $articl): ?>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="blog-single.php" class="blog-entry element-animate" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img style="width: 290; height:193;" src="<?php echo BASE_URL . '/assets/images/' . $articl['image'] ?>" alt="Image placeholder">
              <div class="blog-content-body">
                <div class="post-meta">
                  <span class="category">Food</span>
                  <span class="mr-2"><?php echo date('F j, Y',strtotime($articl['entry_date'])) ?></span> &bullet;
                  <span class="ml-2"><span class="fa fa-comments"></span> 3</span><br>
                  <span class="mr-2">By: <?php echo $articl['name'].' '.$articl['last_name'] ?> </span>
                </div>
                <h2><?php echo $articl['title'] ?></h2>
                <p><?php echo substr($articl['abstract'], 0, 80).'...' ?></p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: You've forgot to add `px` after the numbers: `style="width: 290px; height:193px;"`

Comment: @Triby yes I noticed it, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot writing px in your inline styling, after each number

Comment: thanks, I don't know why I didn't notice that :)) how can I make that responsive? when I change the size of browser window the image gets larger than the div.

Comment: Remove the inline styling, and add a class instead. Then do your styling in that class

Comment: which class exactly does this?

Comment: You have to create your own class, and do the styling yourself. Bootstrap will not help you here